# Counting the number of 1's in binary representation of an integer (MASM) *follow up

Tags: assembly, masm

Hey so I asked this question earlier but I'm running into some new issues with this program.
I'm pretty new to assembly language and I was hoping I could get some help. I'm trying to count the number of ones in a binary representation of an integer. I believe what I'm supposed to is shift the register where I have my input number 32 times and increment each time I come across a 1. I should jump should it not be a 1 to avoid incrementing ebx. I'm still a beginner so I'm still learning the MASM syntax but here is what I have so far:

```
__declspec(naked) unsigned int count(unsigned int v) {
    __asm{
    PUSH EAX
    PUSH EBX
    PUSH ECX


    xor ebx, ebx
    mov ecx, 32

shifting:
    shl eax, 1
    jnc skip_inc
    inc ebx
skip_inc:
    loop shifting


    POP EBX
    POP ECX
    POP EAX

        ret
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that C calling convention expects the return value in eax. Otherwise it looks good. *Oh and you got the `pop ebx`/`pop ecx` in wrong order.

Comment: Thanks for the response! So would that mean that after the look I would simply write "mov eax, ebx"? My issue is that when i test it out with 1 digit binary numbers it works fine. But when I test it out with longer numbers I start getting values that are larger then the expected value.

Comment: Yes, `mov eax, ebx` and obviously delete the `push eax`/`pop eax`.

Comment: Shouldn't the program have a mov eax,v in order to get the input value?

Comment: SSE4 already has a popcount ([POPCNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4#POPCNT_and_LZCNT)) instruction, why don't use it? If you use some old CPUs then there are lots of much more efficient bit counting algorithms in [bithacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#CountBitsSetNaive)

Comment: popcnt was mentioned in the previous version of this same question, but it appears the goal here is a learning exercise.